# Selecting specific rows from CSV and send

Tags: javascript, php, csv

[image]

The above image is the output of CSV file uploaded to an html page using JavaScript.

**Column 1:'name', Column 2: 'email address', Column 3: 'phone number', Column 4:'work group'**.

I have added a check-box to select each row,also I have added a button 'Send' to send the details to another web page(php). The details includes name and email address(only when it is checked) should pass to the other page. Is this possible?
URL for code for uploading:
[Search and match CSV file values with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295537/search-and-match-csv-file-values-with-javascript)

Comment: Regardless of the way you've populated your HTML with the content of the CSV file using JavaScript, Do the entries have some kind of unique identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
    jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
        // prevent the form from actually submitting
        e.preventDefault();

        var rows = [];

        // get a handle to the form, then all checked checkboxes
        // then back up to the rows and loop through each
        jQuery(this).find(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function(){
            var row = [];

            // loop through all the cells that don't have a checkbox
            // and get their text
            jQuery.find('td:not(:has(:checkbox))').each(function(){
                row.push(jQuery(this).text());
            });

            // join all the cell text together, separated by commas (you should
            // probably also wrap each cell with double quotes to make sure
            // commas in the text don't break the CSV)
            rows.push(row.join(','));
        });

        // join all the rows together using new lines as separators
        var csv = rows.join('\n');

        // do what ya need to with the new CSV data, such as AJAXing it back
        // to the server or submitting it as part of the form
    });
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with jQuery and AJAX, should I just include this code with my code, which is provided inside URL that is attached with question.

Comment: @RahulG What do you intend to do with the result? Do you just want to submit the entire thing as a string back to the server, or do you want the processed fields?

Comment: I need to send a mail to the selected email addresses.

Comment: @RahulG the best you can do (from the JS side) is open a new Compose window in your email client with the address pre-populated. The issue is that kicking off a new email with multiple recipient addresses is poorly supported and may not work at all. You're best sending it back to PHP and using a PHP mail library to send.